# Python union of list

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples, union

I'm trying to program a simple admin panel finder. I want to open the file 'site.txt' and the file 'word.txt.' After opening, I want to and join the strings, I can do it only with an input, I can't compare the first site with all the words in word.txt

```
word = []
site = []
selection = input("Insert liste site: ")
f = open(selection,'r+')
d = f.readline().strip()
site.insert(0,d)

wlist = input("Insert wordlist: ")
h = open(wlist, 'r+')
e = h.readline().strip()
word.insert(0,e)
union = str(site[0]+word[0])
print(aaa)
```

Using this I've correct output : http://11.com/admin
But I don't understand how to load all the txt file in site[] and have a clean list in output, I tried also:

```
word = []
site = []
selection = input("Insert liste site: ")
f = open(selection,'r+')
site.append(f.read().split())
print(site)
# Output 
[['htp://11.com/', 'htp://22.com/', 'htp://3.com/', 'htp://4/', 'http://55.com/', 'http://6.com/', 'htp://7.com/', 'htp://8.com/', 'http://99/', 'http://10.com/']] -> output.
```

If I try to union site+word the program print me a list like the one shown above, which isn't joined.

Answer (score 1):

Consirder the following `.txt` files:

site.txt:

```
http://a.com/
http://b.com/
http://c.com/
```

word.txt:

```
admin
admin_login
```

Just use a nested `for` loop in a list comprehension like this:

```
with open(input('Input path of site.txt:\n'),'r') as f:
    sites = f.read().splitlines()
with open(input('Input path of word.txt:\n'),'r') as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines()
results = [site+word for site in sites for word in words]
print(results)
```

And the output will be:

```
 ['http://a.com/admin', 'http://a.com/admin_login', 'http://b.com/admin', 'http://b.com/admin_login', 'http://c.com/admin', 'http://c.com/admin_login']
```